# R training and test sets

Tags: r

So I needed some help with a train and test set that I am creating in R. The goal of the code is to break a data set into a certain amount `k`, and the number of folds the test set will be `i`. It will then return the training and test sets. We assume that `k` will be `5` or `10`.

This is what I have so far.

```
create_sets<-function(df,k,i)
{

  n<-dim(df)[1]

  #fold size
  size<-n/k

  #beggining of test set
  test_start<-(size*i)-(size)+1

  #end of test set
  test_end<-size*i


  indices<-df(test_start,test_end)

  train<-df[indices,]
  test<-df[-indices,]

  return (list(train=train,test=test))

}
```

`df` is just a random data frame of `x` and `y`. That is:

```
x<-c(1,6,7,4,3,5,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,4,5,3,2,1)

y<-c(3,5,6,7,5,4,3,5,7,8,9,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,6)

df<-data.frame(x,y)
```

When I run the code I am returning an error

> Error in df(test_start, test_end) :
>   argument "df2" is missing, with no default

Comment: Your code is breaking because of this line `indices<-df(test_start,test_end)`. What were you hoping to get from that call?

Comment: @PierreLafortune I have figured the solution and it was actually quite simple. indices<-c(test_start,test_end)

Comment: FYI the package 'caret' has a ton of functions you can take right off the shelf for these kinds of validation tasks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach it:

```
n <- nrow(df)
k <- 5
set.seed(10272015)
s <- sample(1:k, n, replace=TRUE)

result <- rep(NA, k)
for (i in 1:k) {
  train <- df[s!=i, ]
  test <- df[s==i,]

  # fit model

  # evaluate

  # result[i] <- evalscore 
}

mean(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for youre help, although I have figured the solution and it was actually quite simple. 

indices<-c(test_start,test_end)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need an index for different subsets,like this:

```
k <- 5
folds <- sample(rep(1:k,length=nrow(df)))
```

then, you can get any one of k subsets by(take 1 for example):

```
df[folds==1,]
```

Comment: Thanks for youre help, although I have figured the solution and it was actually quite simple. 

indices<-c(test_start,test_end)